# Use of "would" for past repeated actions?

Tags: grammaticality, past-habitual

I have heard peo­ple us­ing both of these fol­low­ing sen­tences
while talk­ing about some past re­peated ac­tions, but the first
one sounds a bit un­gram­mat­i­cal, be­cause I have never seen this
sen­tence struc­ture in gram­mar books.

1. When we would go to meet him, he would bring us a cup of tea.
2. When we went to meet him, he would bring us a cup of tea.

What struc­ture do na­tives use?

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear what you want to ask.

Comment: Which natives? People who speak "properly" use 2. But there are regions of the U.S. where lots of people use 1.

Comment: I hear this AE all the time: When we'd go meet him, he'd bring us a cup of tea.

Comment: @PeterShor Eh? I am unaware that 2 is even an option, and I have visited all 50 states and lived and worked in 20 of them. Where in the US is 2 used for past habitual events? [The habitual past is indicated most frequently by the semi-auxiliary verb used to, the auxiliary would, or the simple past tense of a verb. Compare with the past progressive, which instead relies on "to be" to indicate continuous or ongoing action in the past.](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829)

Comment: Even when the item is about as habitual as can be, and nothing is added by marking the habitual with *would*, it is still very common. "Each time the sun would rise" has 36,000 hits. "Each time the sun rose" has more, but they are more frequently in a different construction where *would* appears in an adjacent clause. "Every time I would charge" (my phone) has 275,000 hits.

Comment: As a _British_ native speaker, I find (2) perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @PhilSweet: Let me clarify my earlier comment. I agree that *would* is used for habitual past actions. But it seems to me that the *would* in the second clause covers the habitual aspect, and that that once you have the *would* in the second clause, not only do you not need it in the first clause, but that putting the first *would* in is ungrammatical. However, the comments have convinced me that maybe I'm wrong. (continued).

Comment: A very similar thing actually holds for the future tense. We say *"When you arrive, I will pick you up at the airport,"* not *When you will arrive, I will pick you up at the airport.* The *will* in the second clause makes the *will* in the first clause ungrammatical.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I wasn't correct the first time. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=when+it+rained+they+would%2Cit+would+rain+they+would&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&case_insensitive=true&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhen%20it%20rained%20they%20would%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhen%20it%20rained%20they%20would%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhen%20it%20rained%20they%20would%3B%2Cc0) finds instances of *when it rained they would*, but there are too few of *when it would rain they would* to show up on their chart. But certainly both forms are common in the U.S.

Comment: Ｐｌｅａｓｅ‪ ‪ ‪ｓｔｏｐ‪ ‪ ‪ｐｕｔｔｉｎｇ‪ ‪ ‪ｓｐａｃｅｓ‪ ‪ ‪ｉｎ‪ ‪ ‪ｆｒｏｎｔ‪ ‪ ‪ｏｆ‪ ‪ ‪ｙｏｕｒ‪ ‪ ‪ｐｕｎｃｔｕａｔｉｏｎ‪ ‪ ‪ｍａｒｋｓ，‪ ‪ ‪ａｓ‪ ‪ ‪ｔｈｉｓ‪ ‪ ‪ｉｓ‪ ‪ ‪ｗｒｏｎｇ‪ ‪ ‪ｉｎ‪ ‪ ‪ｗｒｉｔｔｅｎ‪ ‪ ‪Ｅｎｇｌｉｓｈ．‪ ‪ ‪

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, that makes sense now. It seems *habitual* demands the idea of being volitional. I can manage the simple past with some types of repetitive non-volitional happenings, like unwanted behaviors. *Every time I would charge my phone it switched itself off* sorta works. But I would say *Every time I would charge my phone it would switch itself off*. (And then there's what you alluded to - Every time I charged my phone, it would switch itself off).

Comment: I might say the first one if I was talking to tech services about a bug that just started that morning. In that case the emphasis is plainly on the current relevance of the statement, so not really habitual, just repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

For me, writing is more about what sounds properly on the reader's tongue. I think the second is clear, concise, and gets the point across.

When we went to meet him, he would bring us a cup of tea.

Comment: That really isn't very useful advice for non-native speakers (which is who this site is aimed at)